# Add days to date (char column with decimal) in DB2

Tags: db2, iseries, db2-midrange

I have a table named INVOICE_ET which has column of below definition

```
INVDATE CHARACTER 10
```

result of select INVDATE from INVOICE_ET is as below

```
INVDATE
2021-07-31
```

In another table INVOICE_DY, I have a column named INV_DAYS, which has below definition

```
INV_DAYS  DECIMAL 3
```

result of select INV_DAYS from INVOICE_DY is as below

```
INV_DAYS 
88
```

---

Now my question is, I am trying to add INVOICE_DY.INV_DAYS field with INVOICE_ET.INVDATE field, but the char casting is not working,
Please suggest how can I add these two columns. I am trying to get something like below

```
Select a.INVDATE, b.INV_DAYS, (a.INVDATE + b.INV_DAYS) as DUE_DATE 
from INVOICE_ET a 
join INVOICE_DY b 
On a.INVNUM = b.INVNUM //(edited this portion, because join is based on Invoice numbers)
```

```
Result should be 
INVDATE       INV_DAYS       DUE_DATE 
2021-07-31    88             2021-10-27
```

Any suggestions/ thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to Akina and ypercubeᵀᴹ for sorting this one out.

I have modified the query in below fashion and it worked.

```
SELECT INVOICE_ET.INVDATE,
       INVOICE_DY.INV_DAYS,
      (CAST(INVOICE_ET.INVDATE AS date) + INVOICE_DY.INV_DAYS DAYS) AS DUE_DATE 
FROM INVOICE_ET
CROSS JOIN INVOICE_DY;
```

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=3e0d3272dc941c0b13c256bd9fc8a1e4) for more details.

Answer (score -2):

```sql
SELECT INVOICE_ET.INVDATE,
       INVOICE_DY.INV_DAYS,
       ADD_DAYS(DATE(INVOICE_ET.INVDATE), INVOICE_DY.INV_DAYS) AS DUE_DATE 
FROM INVOICE_ET
CROSS JOIN INVOICE_DY;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=de4bc1d961771ab8826a27eda0855df7

Comment: Hi @Akina , thank you for the query, is ADD_DAYS a SQL function ? In my DB2 output  its unable to understand that.

See below snapshot of error- 

  SQL State: 42704 Vendor Code: -204 Message: [SQL0204] ADD_DAYS in *LIBL type *N not found. Cause . . . . . :   ADD_DAYS in *LIBL type *N was not found.

Comment: @mrsorrted https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=functions-add-days

Comment: Db2 for IBM i syntax would be `DATE(INVOICE_ET.INVDATE) + INVOICE_DY.INV_DAYS DAYS` [Datetime operands](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=expressions-datetime-operands-durations)

Comment: Yeah, the problem with DB2 is that there are at least 5 different flavours, all with the same name (DB2) which differ in details and SQL syntax.